# 100vw DIV not showing full width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the gray `div(id='ex-home-bottom-container')` toward the bottom of this page http://patrickbaker.biz/starter-d/ the width of the full page.  Which means breaking it out of the container div.  I've done this using the Firebug style editor in Firefox (it's not live on the site):

```css
#ex-home-bottom-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  left: calc(-50vw+50%);
}
```

That sort of thing has worked in the past but it's not this time.  The div is showing as full width but the left is constrained by the parent DIV.  Which it shouldn't be.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Code shared elsewhere is gone and now the accepted answer does not show what the problem was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Remove `overflow: hidden` from `.site-inner` which is hiding your extending space of ex-home-bottom-container
2. `left` property will not work unless position is specified. Use `margin-left` instead.

```css
#ex-home-bottom-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome :) Yes, you were!

Comment: Hmmm, it's not quite there yet.  Do you mind taking another look (I gotta run my kids to school so back in 10 mins).  http://patrickbaker.biz/starter-d/

Comment: Your applied CSS is not there. There is no left or margin-left right now. Maybe cache issue?

Comment: Thanks.  I can't edit the CSS on the site directly so I'm doing it via email with the site owner.  Turns out you need the spaces around the + in  calc(-50vw + 50%) or it doesn't parse.  Can you edit your answer to put the spaces in?

Comment: @nemmy Thanks for the reminder. `calc()` will indeed not work if there is no space between the operators. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc