# Div with 100vw of width doesn't fit to the screen

Tags: html, css

I have the element `<div id="pageFooter">`, and I wanted to make it full width (windows width) so I applied `width:100vw`, and I didn't wanted it to be fixed/absolute. after applied it, this was the result: the div (footer, at the bottom) is moved slightly to the left.
[image: Result0]

So I searched online and I got to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32351836/8319719) 
Answer. I tried to apply the style and it changed nothing. How Can I fix it?

Minimal working example: (I'm using a little bit of razor, but it doesn't matter for the style.
HTML:

```
    <div class="FooterWrapper lang">
        <footer class="pageFooter">
            <div id="userTools" class="FooterItem">
                <div class="FooterLangSwitcher">
                    <h4>@(Stock_WebApp_v2.Resources.AppCulture.Language)</h4>
                    <hr />
                    @foreach (string value in Stock_WebApp_v2.Resources.LanguagesAvailable.ApplicationLanguages.Split(';'))
                    {
                        <h5 onclick="loc = location.href.split('/');var cul = '@(value.Split(':')[0])';var u = loc[0] + '//' + loc[2] + '/' + cul;for (var x=4;x<loc.length;x++) {u+='/'+loc[x];} window.location.replace(u);">@(value.Split(':')[1])</h5>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.FooterWrapper {
    width: 100vw;
}
.FooterItem {
    color:white;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: What is your code? Create a [mcve]

Comment: Please create a snippet code, and we will help you!

Comment: You need to post a minimal, working example.

Comment: @Roy Are you sure we NEED?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? You can find all properties margin-right < 0px and margin-left < 0px then delete them

Comment: Try `#pageFooter {position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [100vw DIV not showing full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351229/100vw-div-not-showing-full-width)

Comment: @TypeError no. tried as mentioned in post.

Comment: I'm editing the post right now

Comment: If you use 100vw and have a scrollbar on the Y, it will be wider than the screen (because the viewport includes the scrollbar) - why not just use 100%?

Comment: @A.naam Have you tried the solution that I provided?

Comment: Try, `#pageFooter {overflow: none;}`. This would remove the scrollbars from the page.

Comment: @ThucNguyen Not using bootstrap.

Comment: @TypeError yes, even with importants

Comment: The problem is not the scrollbar, but the div "moved" to the left

Comment: have you tried overflow hidden?

Answer (score 2):

add `margin 0` on body

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moh78sgd/2/

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should apply `body { margin:0;}`.

To make full width or height an element and fit with screens you need must follow following steps to avoid unexpected situation:

1. Reset your body, html tag CSS properties like `html,body { padding:0; margin:0;}`
2. To avoid scroll horizontal or vertical with "padding: value" make the element "`box-sizing: border-box;`"
3. Also make sure your element not positioned with "position: absolute/relative/fixed;" and not leave space by positive or negative value by "`top/right/bottom/left:-50px`".

Comment: Done. but still the footer is starting too left, but ended in the right place.[See here](https://imgur.com/a/XzkOuUi)

Comment: Had you added "*{  box-sizing:border-box; }"?

Comment: Yes, and the image was the result

Answer (score 1):

After researching and trying some stuff, I applied

```
.FooterWrapper {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

And the result (Note! I added some 
 to make sure it's not absolute position):
[image: New Result]

Answer (score 0):

Browsers default style may include automatic margins set to your element's parent(s) which will be added to the whole viewport width thus causing the overflow.
You can try to reset the default margin set on an element by adding the CSS rule :

```
margin: 0;
```

or by inlining the style attribute directly on your element :

```
<div style="margin:0;"></div>
```

E.G. - resetting margins on the parent body element :

```css
.FooterWrapper {
  width: 100vw;
}

.FooterItem {
  color: white;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  /* Set body's margin to 0 to ovverride browser defaults */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="FooterWrapper lang">
  <footer class="pageFooter">
    <div id="userTools" class="FooterItem">
      <div class="FooterLangSwitcher">
        <h4>@(Stock_WebApp_v2.Resources.AppCulture.Language)</h4>
        <hr /> @foreach (string value in Stock_WebApp_v2.Resources.LanguagesAvailable.ApplicationLanguages.Split(';')) {
        <h5 onclick="loc = location.href.split('/');var cul = '@(value.Split(':')[0])';var u = loc[0] + '//' + loc[2] + '/' + cul;for (var x=4;x<loc.length;x++) {u+='/'+loc[x];} window.location.replace(u);">@(value.Split(':')[1])</h5>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met with this problem today when doing my side project. I've searched for a long time but got nothing :(

But I solved it after tring to apply `width:100%` on body.
I think this problem was caused by scroll-bar.

This is my test:
add `width: 100vw` to `body`

1. add 51 div [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j85j7.png)
2. add another div [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i8gv.png), and x-scroll-bar and y-scroll-bar appear
3. Then change property-`width: 100vw` to `width: 100%` [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZtHS.png),
   and x-scroll-bar disappear

So I think it may be the reason why `width: 100vw` doesn't fit to screen

This is what I thought. [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6TGs.png)
Maybe it can help you.